# Cannot hide Superfish sub menu on active pages

Tags: navigation

I am using the horizontal NavBar style with Superfish.  When I'm in a section, I do not want its sub-navigation bar to show up.  I only want to see the sub-pages listed whenever I mouse over the parent link.

Example:  Main section is called Products, and I have a sub-section called T-Shirts.  If I click on T-Shirts or Products, it displays the sub-navigation without having to mouse over the Products link again.  The sub-navigation menu becomes persistent when in that section.  I only want to see the list of Products sub pages if I mouse over the main Products link.

I tried setting Path Class to blank instead of "active-trail," but that jacked it up.  Also tried hiding .active-trail with CSS, but no luck there either.

Wondering if this is a Drupal issue with Menu settings or a Superfish issue?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2):

It's both. The active trail stuff has always been, and still is, a big mess, and Superfish herited the problems. You can check [this thread](http://drupal.org/node/1068236) for some information about it, but it remains unclear.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the thread.  I found a solution on that page that involved setting the Path Class to something other than "active-trail" (ex. "customclass").  Not sure why this isn't mentioned in the Superfish documentation, but oh well.

Comment: Then feel free to accept the answer. It will prevent people from reading your question thinking it's not answered.

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with active trail.  I found that changing the version of my superfish library fixed it.  I was running 1.91 of the Superfish module with the master branch of Superfish library.  When I changed the library to the stable branch, the active trail worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked solution:

- open superfish block settings
- change "Path levels" to "0"

See here on the image:
[image]